# omniauth with thin/nginx returning to login screen after authentication - session hash values not populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, thin

I am using omniauth with the google oauth2 provider with https://github.com/zquestz/authpoint as a template. Everything works fine except that the app returns to the login page after authentication rather than going to the home page (or the redirect page). This problem comes only when I use 'thin' with 'nginx'. On my development machine it works fine with the WEBrick server.

After authentication if I go to the homepage explicitly (or reload the page), the app goes to
the home page correctly.

The relevant code is:

```
# Get current provider
def current_user_id
  session[:user_id]
end

# Setup the session if we have a valid user.
def setup_session(user_id)
  session[:user_id] = user_id
end

# Store a url in the session that is safe to go back to (non-volatile)
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

# Redirect back to last good page, or the page you pass it if it doesn't know where to go.
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  location = session[:return_to] || default
  location = default if location == request.fullpath
  redirect_to(location)
  session[:return_to] = nil
  return
end
```

The problem is the session hash is not getting the new values for stored variables after redirect from authorization in redirect_back_or_default so when queried for :user_id in 'current_user_id' it returns nil returning the app to the login page.

I am using ActiveStore as session store.

Comment: This problem goes away if I use a single server in thin. Earlier I was using 3 servers.

Comment: I moved to using passenger with nginx because of another intermittent problem with mysql accesses. The problem is so far not there with passenger. For using passenger with nginx use the excellent guide at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html